# Only allowing admin members of a facebook page to log into an app

Tags: web-applications, facebook, mobile-phones, mobile-application

Hey guys, i'm working on a mobile app which will have profiles driven by facebooks login system.

Basically the rough idea is

FB Page is "tagged" by app user > app posts on facebook page that page has been "tagged" > admin member(s) of tagged facebook page follows unique link into desktop app > app creates a new profile from facebook page.

I can't give very much away, its a top secret project, but basically the app will need to validate that the admin is infact an admin of the page they followed a unique link from ... i want to know if this is possible.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Sorry that its a little confusing, im trying not to give the idea away, any help will be much appreciated, even if its just a yes/no answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

Query the [`page_admin`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_admin/) FQL table.

Also, ideas are cheap. Execution is expensive.

Comment: thanks very much, and execution doesn't always have to be expensive :)